# Returning the result of a node-postgres query

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I am attempting to return the result of a node-postgres query and store it in a variable.  I can manage a console.log just fine, but cannot find a way to return the result so that it is accessible outside of the query method.  I'm at a loss, and know I must be missing something obvious (or multiple obvious things), because if it isn't possible to do this I don't understand the point of node-postgres since all I will ever be able to do is log my results to the console.

I have tried the code below, along with a version using promises, and both receive the same result, 'undefined.' A console.log within the else works fine, but a return does not make the result accessible to the rest of the function.  In the code below, my return comes back as 'undefined' as would a console.log in its place.

```
var selectFrom = function(data, table, condition) {
    var queryResult;
    pool.query(`SELECT ${data} FROM ${table} ${condition}`, function(err, result) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); }
        else { queryResult = result.rows[0][data]; }
    })
    pool.end();
    return queryResult;
}

var result = selectFrom('amount','total_nonfarm_monthly_sa', `WHERE month='2019-08-31'`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your `return queryResult` returns before query is done. You have to somehow wait for the results to come from DB, before returning them. Read about async/await or maybe return a Promise that's resolved with result from the DB.

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for:

```
async function selectFrom(data, table, condition) {
  try {
    const res = await pool.query(
      `SELECT ${data} FROM ${table} ${condition}`
    );
    return res.rows[0][data];
  } catch (err) {
    return err.stack;
  }
}
```

Outside of the previous function:

```
async function whateverFuncName () {
   var result = await selectFrom('amount','total_nonfarm_monthly_sa', `WHERE month='2019-08-31'`);
   console.log(result);
}
```

EDIT: I didn't run this code snippet but the main concept is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

The "query" method is an async call, you should use async/await or Promise.

**With async/await:**

```
await client.connect()
const res = await client.query("SELECT amount FROM total_nonfarm_monthly_sa WHERE month='2019-08-31'");
console.log(res.rows[0]);
await client.end();
```

Edit:
I can see that there's an option of callback, but I would use the async/await

Comment: Sorry, is this only part of the code?  When entering this alone I receive an error message that await is only valid in an async function.

Comment: when you put it inside your function make sure to have async on its declaration like so:  async function myFunc(){ await ... }

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks:

```
var selectFrom = function(data, table, condition, callback) {

    pool.query(`SELECT ${data} FROM ${table} ${condition}`, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
            return callback(err);
        callback(null, result.rows[0][data]);
    })
    pool.end();
}

selectFrom('amount','total_nonfarm_monthly_sa', `WHERE month='2019-08-31'`, function(err, result){
    console.log(err, result);   
});
```

or promises:

```
var selectFrom = function(data, table, condition) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        pool.query(`SELECT ${data} FROM ${table} ${condition}`, function(err, result) {
            if(err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve(result.rows[0][data]);
        })
        pool.end();
    });
}

selectFrom('amount','total_nonfarm_monthly_sa', `WHERE month='2019-08-31'`)
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);    
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);   
});
```

Comment: Thank you, both of these approaches allowed me to log the value via the selectFrom function.  Unfortunately, I am still at a loss as to how to store the value in a variable.  I have tried setting a variable equal to selectFrom, returning 'result' instead of logging it, as well as returning an object where result had been set as the value of a property.  In both cases the output is 'undefined.'